# PHP/MySql - mysql_query isn't Updating Database in MySQL (Worked Before small changes were made)

Tags: php, mysql

PHP Code

```
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    require_once '../' . 'dbconnect.php';

    $isOwner = $_POST['isOwner'];
    $isAdmin = $_POST['isAdmin'];
    $isJrAdmin = $_POST['isJrAdmin'];
    $isMod = $_POST['isMod'];
    $isJrMod = $_POST['isJrMod'];
    $isManager = $_POST['isManager'];
    $isBuilder = $_POST['isBuilder'];
    $isDeveloper = $_POST['isDeveloper'];
    $isGFX = $_POST['isGFX'];
    $isPartner = $_POST['isPartner'];
    $isFamous = $_POST['isFamous'];

    $username = $_POST['username'];

   $confirmedMSG = "<div class='alert alert-success'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>&nbsp;User settings - Set</div>";

    $usererror = false;
    $selecterror = false;
    $confirmed = false;

    if(isset($_POST['btn-confirm'])) {
        if(!empty($username)){
            foreach ($isOwner as $select)
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET isOwner='$select' WHERE userName='$username'");

            }
            foreach ($isAdmin as $select)
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET isAdmin='$select' WHERE userName='$username'");

            }
            foreach ($isJrAdmin as $select)
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET isJrAdmin='$select' WHERE userName='$username'");

            }
            foreach ($isMod as $select)
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET isMod='$select' WHERE userName='$username'");    
            }
            foreach ($isJrMod as $select)
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET isJrMod='$select' WHERE userName='$username'"); 
            }
            foreach ($isManager as $select)
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET isManager='$select' WHERE userName='$username'");
            }
            foreach ($isBuilder as $select)
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET isBuilder='$select' WHERE userName='$username'");    
            }
            foreach ($isDeveloper as $select)
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET isDeveloper='$select' WHERE userName='$username'"); 
            }
            foreach ($isGFX as $select)
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET isGFX='$select' WHERE userName='$username'");
            }
            foreach ($isPartner as $select)
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET isPartner='$select' WHERE userName='$username'");
            }
            foreach ($isFamous as $select)
            {
                mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET isFamous='$select' WHERE userName='$username'");
            }
            $confirmed=true;
        }else{
            $usererror=true;
            $errorMSG = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>Insert username</div>";
        }
    }
```

HTML Code

```
        <section id="main">
            <div class="container">
                <center>Admin Control Panel
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
                        <div class="username">
                            <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Insert username...">
                            <div class="result"></div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <h2>Is User Owner?</h2><br>
                            <select name="isOwner[]">
                                <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                            <br>
                            <h2>Is User Admin?</h2><br>
                            <select name="isAdmin[]">
                                <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                            <br>
                            <h2>Is User JrAdmin?</h2><br>
                            <select name="isJrAdmin[]">
                                <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                            <br>
                            <h2>Is User Mod?</h2><br>
                            <select name="isMod[]">
                                <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                            <br>
                            <h2>Is User JrMod?</h2><br>
                            <select name="isJrMod[]">
                                <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                            <br>
                            <h2>Is User Manager?</h2><br>
                            <select name="isManager[]">
                                <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <h2>Is User Developer?</h2><br>
                            <select name="isDeveloper[]">
                                <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                            <br>
                            <h2>Is User Builder?</h2><br>
                            <select name="isBuilder[]">
                                <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                            <br>
                            <h2>Is User GFX Artist?</h2><br>
                            <select name="isGFX[]">
                                <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                            <br>
                            <h2>Is User Partner?</h2><br>
                            <select name="isPartner[]">
                                <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                            <br>
                            <h2>Is User Famous?</h2><br>
                            <select name="isFamous[]">
                                <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            </select>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="btn-confirm">Set Permissions</button>
                    </form>
```

Here's a query in the same format and works (PHP)

```
if(count($_POST)>0){

            if(isset($username) && $username != $usertitle){
                $query = "SELECT userName FROM legacycl_users WHERE userName='$username'";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
                if($count!=0){
                    $nametaken = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>Name Taken...";
                    $nameerror = true;
                    $nametakenstatus = true;
                }else{
                    if($userChangeDate <= date("Y-m-d")){
                        rename("../../profile/".$usertitle, "../../profile/".$username);
                        $updatedMSG = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span><strong> Settings Updated!</strong> <br> <a href='/profile/$username' class='alert-link'>View changes!</a>";
                        $newDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") + 1, 1);
                        $setDate = date("Y-m-d", $newDate);
                        $newDateMSG = "Next Date for name change: $setDate";
                        mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET userName='$username' WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
                        mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET userChangeDate='$setDate' WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
                        header("Location: http://legacysitetemp.tk/profile/$username");
                    }else{
                        $nameerror=true;
                    }
                }
            }
            $updated=true;
            mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET userYoutube='{$youtube}' WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
            mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET userFacebook='{$facebook}' WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
            mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET userTwitter='{$twitter}' WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
            mysql_query("UPDATE legacycl_users SET userDescription='{$about}' WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);


        }
```

Disregard that there are no ending tags. I didn't copy those.

I'm trying to make it where if any of the options is "Select..." it won't let the Update process. When I made the changes to do so and tried to query, it stopped updating. I did a little test and the values echos the selected option. It just won't update the Database.

I'm not sure why it's not working. Is it because of the foreach function or what?

I'm new to php so there will obviously be some things you won't like.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: While this won't fix your problem, please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: "..before small changes were made." It might help if you told us what those small changes were.

Comment: I removed the "small changes" to retrace my steps. This is where I started off the function and worked before I made the "small changes". All I did was add an if statement: if($select=="Select..."){$selecterror=true;}else{ run update query}